# Search Deconstruction

Tags: search

I would like to deconstruct the search so that I can use CSS to hide the out of the box search field and replace and reposition it with and in house version. Anyone have any experiences they care to share? Is it even doable?

Answer (score 0):

You could easily create a new master page without the search control or modify the current master page to remove the out-of-the-box search control and replace it with yours.